# Does Gitlab AutoDevops support kubernetes secrets as file?

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets, gitlab-autodevops

I am trying out GitLab AutoDevOps, and trying to understand how CI/CD variables work.

In the Settings UI I can set create file and environment variables.

[image]

[According to the documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README#auto-devops-environment-variables), if an variable is prefixed with `K8S_SECRET_` then it appears magically in the deployment.  I can get this to work for env variables, but not for file variables.  In this context I have two questions:

- If this is supported, how do I do it?
- If this not supported, what would you recommend as a work around?  Specifically, I need to be able to mount ssh keys in my pod.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported. You can't use File type variables with `K8S_SECRET_` . These is a workaround.

1. remove first (`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`) and last line (`-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`)
2. Add the rest key as `K8S_SECRET_` `Variable` Type. For an example `K8S_SECRET_SECRET_KEY`
3. This will make your key available in your application as an environment variable. Important thing to notice the new line(\n) will be converted to space.
4. Use a script similar to following in the deployment file.

   `command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    args:
    - |
      mkdir -p /home/certs
      cd /home/certs
      echo $SECRET_KEY > secret.key
      sed -i 's/ /\n/g' secret.key
      sed -i '1s/^/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n/' secret.key 
      sed -i -e '$a-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' secret.key`

Comment: I think the newlines would be preserved if you used double quotes in `echo "$SECRET_KEY" > secret.key`.